# How do I bind scroll left in Lua in G hub?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have a Logitech G502 Hero. I want to bind my scroll left ,G11, to an auto clicker. I managed to do it by binding it to middle click and in Lua using `IsMouseButtonPressed(2)`, however that removes the functionality of my middle click. Is there any way around this?

Mouse binds:

[image: 1]

Code:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
Sleep(50)
while(IsMouseButtonPressed(2)) do
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
Sleep(40)
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Bind scroll left (G11) to the command "Back".
   This will remove the functionality of your "Back" G4 button, but Middle Click will work.
2. Set the script:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 11 then
    repeat
      PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
      PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
      PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
      PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
      Sleep(40)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)  -- 4 = Back
  end
end
```